# heroku application crashing everytime

Tags: python-3.x

i tried to deploy a telegram bot using heroku but its throwing some errors

tried rebuilding the app multiple times even rechecked the code and changed some stuff in the settings but nothing worked

```
 2019-04-28T20:00:06.366752+00:00 app[api]:`enter code here` Release v9 created by user testpaypal580@gmail.com
    2019-04-28T20:00:06.366752+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0ac91a7b by user testpaypal580@gmail.com
    2019-04-28T20:00:06.892646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2019-04-28T20:00:10.782109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python3 dwsongs-normal.py`
    2019-04-28T20:00:12.946054+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:91: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.25.1) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
    2019-04-28T20:00:12.946075+00:00 app[web.1]: RequestsDependencyWarning)
    2019-04-28T20:00:15.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.102728+00:00 app[web.1]: 1):Free
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.102853+00:00 app[web.1]: 2):Strict
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.103267+00:00 app[web.1]: :ChooseTraceback (most recent call last):
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.103306+00:00 app[web.1]: File "dwsongs-normal.py", line 787, in <module>
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.104544+00:00 app[web.1]: ans = input(":Choose")
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.104735+00:00 app[web.1]: EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.279581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2019-04-28T20:00:17.263327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

this is the log i get

any help would be appreciated

code:

```
try:
   print("1):Free")
   print("2):Strict")
   ans = input("Choose:")
   if ans == "1":
    bot.message_loop({
                      "chat": start,
                      "callback_query": download,
                      "inline_query": search,
                      "chosen_inline_result": up
                     })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your input and print statements. Your program will crash if it's printing to stdout without there being one. You can instead redirect your output to /dev/null by ending your script with `> /dev/null` e.g. `python3 dwsongs-normal.py > /dev/null`

Comment: im not really familiar with programming still a beginner so theres the code where it throws the error i hope you can figure out whats wrong with it

try:
   print("1):Free")
   print("2):Strict")
   ans = input("Choose:")
   if ans == "1":
    bot.message_loop({
                      "chat": start,
                      "callback_query": download,
                      "inline_query": search,
                      "chosen_inline_result": up
                     })

Comment: Please update the question with the snippet you just commented. Formatting is off in the comments

Comment: Also, why do you want to use Heroku for a console (terminal) application. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: also this is a telegram bot actually 
if you want more info let me know

Comment: What I meant by a terminal application, is that your program prints and accepts inputs from a terminal. Heroku is used to deploy web applications. Where you tyoically interact through a web page

Comment: Your error is caused by the fact that your program interacts with the terminal, when there isn't one.

Comment: alright is there anyway to make it work with telegram?
also after thinking about it the code wasnt intended to be used with heroku but with linux vps

Comment: If you want a solution that just works. remove the print and input statements and hard-code your inputs. Instead of having ans = input(...) Replace it with ans = "your actual input"

Comment: If you're still facing errors, then please uodate your question with the error message you're getting.

Comment: idk whats wrong tbh but it seems just as you've said its not intented to be used with heroku heres the source code and see if you can do something about it contact me on telegram if you want 
https://github.com/An0nimia/DeezloaderRMX_bot